# why roscd changes to install directory in colcon build?

Tags: ros, colcon, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I used to use caktin_make to build my ROS pakcage, and after catkin_make, when i use command `roscd package_name`, and it changes to packge location under `src` directory. Recently i change `catkin_make` to `colcon build`, i found that roscd changes to`install` directory after colcon build, so i am confused.
i have two question:

1. why in colcon build, roscd changes to install directory? i think this mechanism **brings a lot of inconvenience**, for example, when i have some config file in package directory, i have to install all these config files to install directory, and may make mistake of the relative path of config file.
2. how does roscd work? how does it found the package location?

i use **kinetic ros**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327222/why-roscd-changes-to-install-directory-in-colcon-build?/) by [ming](https://answers.ros.org/users/37359/ming/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-06-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`roscd` changes to a location based on where the `package.xml` file of a ROS package was found.

After you built and installed a package the installed files do not have any reference to the source files. E.g. consider a Debian package which is basically an installed package. The source files are not even present in the Debian package. Similar after installing you could delete your source files.

This behavior is not specific to `colcon` but happens the same with any other tool when you actually install the packages and don't use the devel space (which is a custom ROS catkin thing).

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2019-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0